# Import utf-8 headings Maatwebsite Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.1, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using Maatwebsite in Laravel and it's very good option for excel works but I have one problem .. I have excel sheet with arabic heading, so when I import it , it converted to understand-less english character to fit array key .. So What is the solution for my problem?

Comment: what do you mean by: "converted to understand-less english character to fit array key"?

Comment: I mean if I have heading like $arr["ميامي"] it convert it to $arr["mymy"]

Comment: must be a problem with encoding then. I do not know maatwebsite-excel, but you should look into encoding issues. I think you need to enforce UTF8 somehow.

Comment: so how to enforce it ?

Comment: too much for a comment. I'll post it as an answer, but I don't know if it helps. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late, but for someone else that may have the same problem, you should change the value of "heading" key to "original" in "import" array of config/excel.php file..

```
'import' => [
    ...
    'heading' => 'original',
],
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import

Look up the header about import encoding.

From thoose pages:

```
// When utilising a closure, you can pass the input encoding as third parameter.
Excel::load('filename.csv', function($reader) {

}, 'UTF-8');

// or without a closure, you can use it as second parameter.
Excel::load('filename.csv', 'UTF-8');
```

Does that solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can implements the Interface of WithCustomCsvSettings, in your class import

Example:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;


class ArticlesImport implements ToCollection, WithCustomCsvSettings
{
  public function collection(Collection $rows)
  { 
    // do something
  }

  public function getCsvSettings(): array
  {
    # Define your custom import settings for only this class
    return [
        'input_encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'delimiter' => ";"
    ];
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late but this workerd for me, instead of a modifying import.php, in your controller add this

```
config(['excel.import.heading' => 'original' ]);
```