# Laravel excel can't handle japanese heading properly

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am using laravel excel to upload a excel file. The file contains heading at the very top. However, when the heading is in Japanese it is not being processed properly.

For example, if my file is like

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| bango   | name   | level |
+---------+--------+-------+
| nihongo | 日本語 | 8     |
+---------+--------+-------+
| test01  | test01 | 12    |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

It gives the following output,

[image]

This is the correct output.
However, when I change the heading to include Japanese then it doesn't work correctly. 
My file is like,

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| 番号    | 名前   | ラベル |
+---------+--------+--------+
| nihongo | 日本語 | 8      |
+---------+--------+--------+
| test01  | test01 | 12     |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

The output becomes

[image]

I tested to mix this and put some headers in English and some in Japanese.
My file is like,

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| 番号    | name   | ラベル |
+---------+--------+--------+
| nihongo | 日本語 | 8      |
+---------+--------+--------+
| test01  | test01 | 12     |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

And my result becomes,

[image]

Although, the result gives `name` values correctly but the serial is incorrect. `name` values should be before `level` but it is not.

My controller function is like,

```
public function post($id)
    {
        $array  = (new DeliveryImport)->toArray(request('file'));
        dd($array);
    }
```

And my DeliveryImport.php is like,

```
class DeliveryImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;
    public function model(array $row)
    {
    }
}
```

Please, note that, the code doesn't work only when there are Japanese on heading. If there is Japanese on other places then it works without a problem.

Comment: Might be related to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397671/import-utf-8-headings-maatwebsite-laravel) regarding the heading encoding.

Comment: Yes. It was related to that answer. I solved the problem. :D

Comment: Not entirely related, but "level" in katakana is 「レベル」. What you have here is 「ラベル」, which means "label".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The solution is to change in `config/excel.php`.

In that file find `imports' => 'heading_row'`.

Then change the `formatter` from `slug` to `none`.

It worked flawlessly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also put these above, outside your function

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;
HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).